# join up two or more ImageViews

Tags: java, android, imageview

I have 4 Framelayouts with 2 ImageViews(one visible, one invisible) in my layout. After onClick on the first ImageView, in the Framelayout, its rotating to the second ImageView. Like in this example(http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html). It works fine, but is there any option to combine two or more ImageViews? So if I click on the first image(android:id="@+id/HotView1") my android:id="@+id/HotView2" and android:id="@+id/WarmView2" rotate togehter as one Image?

Sure, I can rotate each view sequentially, but that does not look good because of the camera-angle while rotation.Is there any easy and fast solution?

```
[...]
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HotView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hot_notactiv" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/HotView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hot_activ" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/WarmView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/warm_notactiv" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/WarmView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/warm_activ" />
    </FrameLayout>
[...]
```

Comment: Add both images in one Linear Or Relative Layout give animation to that whole layout.

Comment: But it but it depends... sometimes I would like to combine the Images sometimes not. And my rotation method looks like this : private void applyRotation(float start, float end, ImageView image1,ImageView image2). So I need an ImageView for rotating

Answer (score 0):

Hi first off all give ids to the LinearLayout and ImageView that you want to animate. So that you can reference to them.

Then define one function that will animate the passed view like :

```
public void myAnimation(View viewToAnimate) {
 // Your code for animating which will be comman
}
```

Now get references of both LinearLayout and ImageView, check condition for which view to animate, like :

```
if(wantToAnimateLinearLayout == true) {
   myAnimation(linearLayoutReference);
} else {
  myAnimation(imageViewReference);
}
```